# Geb Spock - Repeating the Entire Test Suite

Tags: spock, geb

In combination with Geb and Spock, is there a way to iterate the entire test suite?

As an example, consider a test suite class - MyExampleTestSpec with two specs in it.

```
Class MyExampleTestSpec extends GebSpec {

  def "testSpec1"(){
    when:
    then:
  }

  def "testSpec2"(){
   given:
   when:
   then:

   where:
 }
}
```

A single Spec can be re-iterated using the "where" clause. But what is the option to re-iterate the entire suite?

Please let me know.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: If you mean data driven specs with `re-iterate`, then I can tell you that spock does not provide such a feature.

Answer (score 0):

So it really depends on what you are testing. There is no way to do a where on a class level by default. you could make an annotation to pull from a source and do a replace on values.

Something I have done is have a more generic test. Notice that parameters can be inserted into the BDD method comments. you could make these each a custom parameter. the only issue is that you would need to have the same number of elements each time.

```
@Unroll
def "Failed request to obtain Oath Token by #failure"(){
    given: "a user is attempting to use the 'Obtain OAuth Token' endpoint"
    when: "the Content-Type is set to #content_type"
        request.setContentType(content_type)
    and: "the Accept type is set to #accept"
        request.addHeader("Accept", accept)
    and: "the user sets the client_id as #clientId"
    and: "the user set the client_secret as #clientSecret"
    and: "the grant_type is set as #grantType"
    and: "the request type is #requestType"
        request.setPostBody(ApiRequestBody.oAuthBody(client_id:clientId,client_secret:clientSecret,grant_type:grantType))
        response = request.postExecute()
    then: "an appropriate status code (#status) is returned"
        response.status == status
    and: "the error response is '#error_message'"
        response.data.errors[0].message == error_message
    and: "the error code is #error_code"
        response.data.errors[0].code == error_code
    and: "the response type is #response_type"
        response.contentType == response_type
    where:
    [failure, content_type, accept, clientId, clientSecret, grantType, requestType, status, error_message, error_code, response_type] <<
            [
                    ["wrong grant_type",ContentType.URLENC,ContentType.JSON,ID,SECRET,"${GRANT}_wrong","POST", ApiUtility.ERRORS.'113'.status, ApiUtility.ERRORS.'113'.message, ApiUtility.ERRORS.'113'.code, ContentType.JSON.toString()],
                    ["wrong Client_Secret",ContentType.URLENC,ContentType.JSON,ID,"${SECRET}_Wrong",GRANT,"POST", ApiUtility.ERRORS.'112'.status, ApiUtility.ERRORS.'112'.message, ApiUtility.ERRORS.'112'.code, ContentType.JSON.toString()],
                    ["wrong Client_ID",ContentType.URLENC,ContentType.JSON,"${ID}_Wrong",SECRET,GRANT,"POST", ApiUtility.ERRORS.'112'.status, ApiUtility.ERRORS.'112'.message, ApiUtility.ERRORS.'112'.code, ContentType.JSON.toString()],
                    ["mismatch of ID and Secret",ContentType.URLENC,ContentType.JSON,ID,otherToken,GRANT,"POST", ApiUtility.ERRORS.'112'.status, ApiUtility.ERRORS.'112'.message, ApiUtility.ERRORS.'112'.code, ContentType.JSON.toString()],
                    ["an empty body",ContentType.URLENC,ContentType.JSON,"","","","POST", ApiUtility.ERRORS.'114'.status, "Missing or invalid parameters client_id,client_secret,grant_type", ApiUtility.ERRORS.'114'.code, ContentType.JSON.toString()],
                    ["an empty grant_type",ContentType.URLENC,ContentType.JSON,ID,SECRET,"","POST", ApiUtility.ERRORS.'114'.status, "Missing or invalid parameters grant_type", ApiUtility.ERRORS.'114'.code, ContentType.JSON.toString()],
                    ["an empty Client_Secret",ContentType.URLENC,ContentType.JSON,ID,"",GRANT,"POST", ApiUtility.ERRORS.'114'.status, "Missing or invalid parameters client_secret", ApiUtility.ERRORS.'114'.code, ContentType.JSON.toString()],
                    ["an empty Client_ID",ContentType.URLENC,ContentType.JSON,"",SECRET,GRANT,"POST", ApiUtility.ERRORS.'114'.status, "Missing or invalid parameters client_id", ApiUtility.ERRORS.'114'.code, ContentType.JSON.toString()],
                    ["wrong Content_Type",ContentType.JSON,ContentType.JSON,ID,SECRET,GRANT,"POST", ApiUtility.ERRORS.'114'.status, "Missing or invalid parameters client_id,client_secret,grant_type", ApiUtility.ERRORS.'114'.code, ContentType.JSON.toString()]
            ]
}
```